# Working with directories and data in java

Tags: java, libraries, directory

I'm looking to get pointed in the right direction for this problem. I have two data sets with identical directory structures, sub directories, and the same name for data files underneath with different values in the data files. The difference between them is that each directory has a different time stamp, and the values in the data files are different.

What I want to do is pick two Data.txt files in the two directories at the same time then process them and move on to other sub directories until each time stamp directory is finished. Are there any libraries that could help manage this process or does anyone have any ideas that could help?

TimeStamp 1

```
General Directory                              
      subdirectories                                  
               Data.txt
```

TimeStamp 2

```
General Directory                              
      subdirectories                                  
               Data.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use File.listFiles() to traverse each directory and call directories recursively to process sub-directories. You can use File.lastModified() to get the modification date of a file

Comment: Thanks, what If the data files don't have the same amount of data, I don't want to move on to the next set of files until i process the two I have. Its more Like I have to process the data in the data files at the same time, like if me and you were reading the same book paragraph by paragraph and then had to give our analysis to a third party, then we move on to the next paragraph.

Comment: You can check the File.length() as well if you wish. Are you saying you have a process which could be writing to the file while you are reading it? What do the two processes do?

Comment: I don't have to write to it, I just have the read the values and send them off for processing. I have to do this incrementally because the process step eats up memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache Commons IO [DirectoryWalker](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html) but I would go for the `File.listFiles()` already mentioned as it is simple enough to recurse a directory tree.